# depth first traversal of a tree using generators in python

Tags: python, compiler-construction, generator, abstract-syntax-tree, depth-first-search

At the moment, I'm programming a compiler for a very small subset of Python in Python. I already managed to construct a syntax tree but I got some problems with coding the tree traversal (which is essential for generating code). So I'll first go along with showing you my data structures:

```
class AbstractSyntaxTree(object):
    def __init__(self, startSymbol):
        self.root = Node(startSymbol, val=None)
        self.nodes = [self.root]

    def addNode(self, name, val, parentId):
        parent = self.nodes[parentId]
        self.nodes.append(Node(name=name, val=val, parent=parent))
        return len(self.nodes)-1

    def getLastId(self):
        return len(self.nodes)-1

    def __iter__(self):
        for node in self.root:
            yield node
```

This is my node definition:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, val, parent=None):
        self.name = name
        self.val = val
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []

        if parent:
            parent.children.append(self)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self
        for child in self.children:
            for node in child:
                yield node
```

My parser is a recursive descent parser, where every grammar symbol is a function calling other grammar symbols. `program` is my start symbol.

```
def program(self, indentLvl=0):
    parent = self.synTree.getLastId()
    if self.smellAndConsume(TOK.EOF, parentId=parent): return
    self.smellAndConsume(TOK.NEWL, parentId=parent)
    self.synTree.addNode(name=VAR.statement, val=None, parentId=parent)
    self.statement()
    while self.accept and not self.isConsumable(TOK.EOF):
        self.consume(TOK.NEWL, parentId=parent)
        self.synTree.addNode(name=VAR.statement, val=None, parentId=parent)
        self.statement()
    self.consume(TOK.EOF, parentId=parent)
```

Now is was curious, if after succesful parsing I would be able to print all my nodes in the syntax tree by iterating it depth first using my `__iter__` generator defined in `Node` and `AbstractSyntaxTree`. But

```
def test_tree_traversal():
    for node in miniPyGrammar.synTree:
        print(node)
```

doesn't print all the nodes! When I debugged my code, I realized, that my root node doesnt't have any children in its children list, although I call `addNode` with the root nodes id. Does anyone have a clue what's happening here?

If you need more information or more code snippets, feel free to ask.

edit: I just found the solution (although I still find it odd what's happening here.) This code now behaves as expected:

```
def test_tree_traversal(code):
    grammar = Grammar()
    grammar.parse(code)
    for node in grammar.synTree:
        print(node)

def execute_tests():
    for name, code in programs.items():
        parse_test(name, code)
        test_tree_traversal(code)
```

Before I had a global Grammar object and execute_tests would call parse on that grammar, after which i ran test_tree_traversal, which accesses the grammar-object synTree. Strangely, in between the calls, the garbage collection deleted some of the nodes in the AST. Why I suppose it's the garbage collection? Because the behaviour was nondeterministic.

edit: this was the error-prone code:
notice the only difference is that I instantiate a new grammar object before executing a test. Grammar has a method ´parse´ which returns true if the program is syntactically correct and constructs an AST which is accessible via Grammar.synTree.

```
miniPyGrammar = Grammar()

def parse_test(
    programName: str,
    programCode: str):
    success = miniPyGrammar.parse(programCode)
    if success:
        print('{} is a valid miniPyProgram :)'.format(programName))
    else:
        print('{} is not a valid miniPyProgram'.format(programName))
    print(miniPyGrammar.synTree)

def tree_traversal(code):
    for node in miniPyGrammar.synTree:
        print(node)

def execute_tests():
    for name, code in programs.items():
        parse_test(name, code)
        tree_traversal(code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    execute_tests()
```

Comment: I don't think you're going to get an answer about the non-working version of your code, because you haven't adequately described it. We can't troubleshoot code we can't see! In `for node in miniPyGrammar.synTree:`, what is `miniPyGrammar` and why do you expect it to hold your syntax tree? Are you sure there aren't any bugs in any of your parser's methods that are breaking the tree? You've only shown us one method, and I don't understand half of what it's doing since it's calling methods you haven't shown. Try to make a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Yeah this is kind of true but because I didn't know where the error came from, I didn't know which parts of my code to show. I thought the problem probably came from wrong iterator code. I will create another edit to point out where the problem was before.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to iterate over your tree, I recommend using the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) instead. This approach allows you easily modularize your abstract syntax tree traversal.

Note that with using this approach, you would have to create specfic classes for each node type in the tree. For example, you could have a `Operator` class for operator nodes, a `FunctionCall` class for function call nodes, etc.

Here is a very simple example of the vistor pattern for an AST that should get you started. The AST consists of `Operator` nodes for operators, and `Number` nodes for numbers:

```
class Node:
    pass


class Operator(Node):
    def __init__(self, op, left, right):
        self.op = op
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


class Number(Node):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


class AstWalker:
    def visit(self, node):
        name = 'visit_' + node.__class__.__name__
        vistor = getattr(self, name, self.missing)
        vistor(node)

    def missing(self, node):
        name = node.__class__.__name__
        raise Exception('No visitor method for node type: ' + name)

    def visit_Operator(self, node):
        print('operator:', node.op)
        self.visit(node.left)
        self.visit(node.right)

    def visit_Number(self, node):
        print('number:', node.value)


# The ast represents the expression:
#
# (1 * 5) - (3 / 5)
#
ast = Operator(op='-',
        left=Operator(op='*', 
                   left=Number(1), 
                   right=Number(5)
        ),

        right=Operator(op='/', 
                   left=Number(3), 
                   right=Number(5)
        )
)

walker = AstWalker()
walker.visit(ast)
```

The output of the above code is:

```
operator: -
operator: *
number: 1
number: 5
operator: /
number: 3
number: 5
```

The interesting part of the above code is the `AstWalker` class. It's here that we implement the pattern. Here's a quick rundown.

The `visit` method is the meat of the above code. It's where the magic happens. To keep a long story short, `visit` takes one argument `node`. This will be either an `Operator` node or a `Number`. It then takes the name of the node's class by using `node.__class__.__name__`. As you can see, I perpended the name with `visit` since the visitor method's for each node in the tree - `visit_Operator` and `visit_Number` have visit.

Lastly in `self.visit`, I use `getattr` to get the correct visitor method from the class. If the node is a `Number` `getattr` will return the `visit_Number` method. The same applies to `Operator`. The visitor method is then called and `node` is passed in.

If we find that somehow the `node` object passed in doesn't have a visitor method, we return `self.missing` and call it. `self.missing` simple reports which node object we encountered didn't have a visitor method.

As said above, each visitor method takes one argument `node`. The current node were visiting. In the example above, I simply print the attributes of each `node`. It could easily be modified however to generate bytecode.

Comment: Thanks four your alternative suggestion! But I'm still curious why my code does not print all my nodes. Do you have any suggestions on that?

Comment: I'm afraid not, @drssdinblck. The code you should really doesn't provide enough context to see what the matter is. But from looking at the code samples from your question, you seem a bit confused about what the exact result of the parser should be. I recommend reading [this](http://parsingintro.sourceforge.net/) article. It has some nice examples demonstrating  AST construction. Perhaps it will help.

Comment: Hmm I'm having a suspicion. I suppose there could be an error with the python garbage collection, because when I was debugging my code, suddenly nodes where erased from node.children without having even changed anything. Plus my code seems to be nondeterministic. Sometimes, I get correct prints of my AST, sometimes not.